# Positive definiteness of a matrix irrespective of the value of a scalar parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Given $Q=Q^\top>0$ and $G=G^\top>0$, is the real symmetric matrix $A =\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\alpha}Q+2C^\top C & -C^\top(I+G)\\ -(I+G)C & 2G \end{bmatrix}$ positive definite for **any** value of $\alpha>0$?

It looks straightforward that the definiteness holds for sufficiently small $\alpha>0$. However, it seems true even for any positive $\alpha$, which I am not being able to prove. Help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is not true in general. I will show you a counter example below, but to get some intuition about why it cannot be true, consider the quadratic form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix}^\top
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\alpha}Q+2C^\top C & -C^\top(I+G) \\
-(I+G)C & 2G
\end{pmatrix}
}_A
\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for any choice of vectors $u,v$ and positive scalar $\alpha$. If the assertion was true, this quadratic form would be non-negative. Note that we may rewrite this as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Cu \\
v
\end{pmatrix}^\top
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
2I & -(I+G) \\
-(I+G) & 2G
\end{pmatrix}
}_{M}
\begin{pmatrix}
Cu \\
v
\end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{\alpha} u^\top Q u.
$$
By the assumption on $Q$, the rightmost term is positive. It remains to investigate the matrix $M$. To do so, note that by assumption, $G>0$, whence it suffices to check whether the Schur complement $S$ with respect to the bottom right entry of $M$ is positive semi-definite. We have
$$
S = 2G - \frac{1}{2}(I+G)(I+G) = -\frac{1}{2}(G-I)^2,
$$
which is *negative* semidefinite. Thus, $M$ is not of (semi)definite sign unless $G = I$. Therefore, for any $\alpha$ we can pick $G$ "sufficiently large" (in some sense) such that the resulting matrix $A$ is indefinite.

As an example, consider a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ with $\alpha = Q = C = 1$ and $G = 4$. In other words,
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -5 \\
-5 & 8
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1 = 11.0902$ and $\lambda_2 = -0.0902$ to four decimal places.

Comment: thanks for your help.
I understand that the assertion was not true in general. I actually have identified an issue while formulating the matrix $A$. The matrix should have been
$A =\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\alpha}Q+2GC^\top CG & -2GC^\top\\ -2CG & 2I \end{bmatrix}$, which clearly is positive definite for any positive value of $\alpha$.

Comment: I see, yes that changes things a bit. Then you can factor out $CG$ in the quadratic form I mentioned, and positive definiteness follows immediately as you say. I'm glad you solved your problem. May I ask in what context this matrix arises?

Comment: I was trying to prove stability of a system, in the context of control theory, using Lyapunov analysis. Though the actual matrices look different, I simplified it multi-folds to pose the question without bringing in unnecessary complexities.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward calculation shows that the Schur complement of $G$ in $A$ is given by
$$
A/G=\frac1\alpha Q^{1/2}\left[I- \frac\alpha2Q^{-1/2}C^\top(G^{1/2}-G^{-1/2})^2CQ^{-1/2}\right]Q^{1/2}.
$$
As $G$ is positive definite, $A>0$ if and only if $A/G>0$. Hence $A>0$ iff
$$
\alpha<\frac2{\rho\left(Q^{-1/2}C^\top (G^{1/2}-G^{-1/2})^2CQ^{-1/2}\right)}
$$
where $\rho(\cdot)$ denotes the spectral radius of a matrix.

Comment: thanks for your help.
I actually have identified an issue while formulating the matrix $A$. The matrix should have been
$A =\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\alpha}Q+2GC^\top CG & -2GC^\top\\ -2CG & 2I \end{bmatrix}$, which clearly is positive definite for any positive value of $\alpha$.